# Basic proof of statement in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Abelian_Quotient_Group

The third step (in both proofs) is something I am having trouble seeing. The theorem itself is not difficult to prove, but it is much cleaner this way. However, I am not understanding why $ab(ba)^{-1} \in H$ implies $abH = baH$, or the reverse implication. I tried proving it myself, or googling the result, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is normal, so commutes with everything in $G$.  Then \begin{align*}
    &     & abH &= baH \\
    &\iff & abHa^{-1} &= baHa^{-1} \\
    &\iff & abHa^{-1}b^{-1} &= baHa^{-1}b^{-1} \\
    &\iff & aba^{-1}Hb^{-1} &= baa^{-1}Hb^{-1} \\
    &\iff & aba^{-1}b^{-1}H &= baa^{-1}b^{-1}H \\
    &\iff & ab(ba)^{-1}H &= bb^{-1}H \\
    &\iff & ab(ba)^{-1}H &= H \\
\end{align*} so $ab(ba)^{-1} \in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication on the left is a bijection, so that $(ab)^{-1}(abH)=H$, but $abH=baH$, so we have $b^{-1}a^{-1}baH=H$.  Since $1\in H$, we see that $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba\in H$.  This shows one side of the implication, and the other side of the implication follows from similar reasoning.  The key to the proof is the fact that multiplication on the left is a bijection.